# react-dnd simple sortable example ES6 instead of ES7

Tags: reactjs, decorator, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm attempting to follow this example:

https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/tree/master/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple

But the code is using ES7 and I don't know how to replace the decorators  and the decorate dependency in this file:

https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/blob/master/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple/Card.js

I've tried to read about decorators but I just don't understand it. I'm hoping someone can give an ES6 example of the Card.js code so I can get a better idea of what's going on and rewrite that example for my own use.

Comment: You may try to just compile the ES7 to ES6, see what it does, and then put that into your own code.

Comment: You should have a look at the [documentation](http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-source.html), which contains examples ins ES5, 6 and 7

Comment: Have you been able to find/make one? I am farily new to React and ES6 and I am struggling with it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_.flow` is a nice solution, but it's not necessary to install underscore and add an import just for this one task.

`DragSource()` returns a function that takes a React component class as input and returns a new React component class which will act as a drag source. `DropTarget()` does the same thing. knowing this, we can simply write:

```
DragSource(_itemType_, _sourceSpecification_, _sourceCollector_)(
    DropTarget(_itemType_, _targetSpecification, _targetCollector_)(YourComponent))
```

`DropTarget(/*...*/)(YourComponent)` will return a target component class, and `DragSource(/*...*/)` can read in that newly created component class and spit out a final component class that is both a drop target and a drag source.

a little verbose, but it gets the job done without using an outside library, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

you probably stumbled across the part in the example where the ES7 decorators are stacked:

```
@DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, connect => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
}))
@DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
}))
```

The solution to implement the equivalent code in ES5 or ES6 is given here - http://gaearon.github.io/react-dnd/docs-faq.html - using the lodash flow function to combine the functions- however there is a little mistake in the example code where it's missing Array brackets. The correct code should therefore be:

```
export default flow([
  DragSource(/* ... */),
  DropTarget(/* ... */)]
)(YourComponent);
```

P.S. the Babel REPL doesn't seem to support decorators even with Stage 1 activated, I get the following error:

```
repl: Decorators are not supported yet in 6.x pending proposal update.
  3 |   connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
  4 | }))
> 5 | export default class Card extends Component {
    |                ^
  6 |   render() { 
  7 |     return <div>asdas</div>
  8 |   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't understand any es6\7 features you always can go to babeljs.io and try it out. Regarding decorators - A function decorator accepts a function, wraps (or decorates) it’s call and returns the wrapper, which alters default behavior. You can see examples and read about it here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/decorators

[**Here** is your example in babeljs](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0A%40DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD%2C%20cardTarget%2C%20connect%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20connectDropTarget%3A%20connect.dropTarget()%0A%7D))%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Card%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20render()%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%3Easdas%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Comment: Babel turns the code in to ES5.. am I correct in assuming so?

Comment: Yes, babel turns ES 6\7 -> ES5.

Comment: Is there a way to change ES7 to ES6 instead?

Comment: I don't know. But i think transpiled decorators would be look similar in es 6 and es 7. So decorator it's function which recieves arguments `ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, connect => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
})` and returns function which recieves class. It should looks smth like this: http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0ADropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD%2C%20cardTarget%2C%20connect%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0A%20%20connectDropTarget%3A%20connect.dropTarget()%0A%7D))(Test)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [HongJheLi](https://github.com/HongJheLi) made a repo with the example remade in ES6: https://github.com/HongJheLi

The meat of the issue:

```
export default flow([
  DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
  })),
  DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, connect => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  }))
])(Card);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Method 1.

Nested HOC

```
export default DragSource()(DropTarget()(Component));
```

#### Method 2.

Use `flow` method from `lodash`

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export default _.flow([DragSource(), DropTarget()])(Component);
```

#### Method 3.

Use redux `compose`

```
import { compose } from 'redux';

export default compose(DragSource(), DropTarget())(Component)
```